# python game highscore calculation

Tags: python

Is there a formula I can use for python code to calculate a score with the variables `moves` and `time`? The higher the time the lower the score, or if the number of moves is more, then the time should be lower.

I did this but if the time is higher the score becomes lower:

```
Score = ((90000000 - (moves/10))*int(seconds/100))/1000000
```

Comment: See [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need to see some code, see what you tried, etc.

Comment: depends on the situation. a simple solution could be `score = maxScore - k1*time - k2*moves`.

Comment: @frederick99 but what does the k1 and k2 points to?

Comment: `k1` and `k2` are constants that you can vary depending on the weight `time` and `moves` carry in calculating the score. if you think no of moves is less important that finishing the game in lesser time, `k2` will be lesser that `k1`.

Comment: At the very least, you should be inversely proprtional to time, not directly proportional: use `/` instead of `*`, don't cast to `int` until the very end of the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of functions that do what you want. What you are building can be modeled by a simple curve. So how do you want the curve to behave?

You can have a linear curve that goes straight towards zero. Or you can have an exponential decay where the score approaches zero but never reaches it.

[image: Exponential Decay]

You'd have to play around with the values, but the formula for modelling exponential decay is `N*math.exp(-x)` where N is the maximum number of points, and x is some weighted combination of time and number of moves. For instance,

`x = A * time + B * moves #where X and Y are some multipliers of your choice`

A linear curve is easiest though. Just calculate a value x as shown above, and subtract it from your top score number `N`. If the resulting score is below zero, set it to zero and that's your output.